# PHP: redirect to blog pages by selectbox on HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, header

I'm a newbie on PHP programming but I have to use it for a page in my blog that permit the users to search inside the blog using a radiobox and a selectbox. I've read some discussion about it but I can't find the error in my code.

This is my situation: I would permit a searching by brand or by model or by cc in my blog that talks about motorcycles, so I have a form with three radiobox that enables/disables the three selectboxes below. One for each category above-named. Clicking a button, the user will be redirected to the respective link /brand/ or /model/ or /cc/.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form name="admin" method="post" action="/search.php">
<input type="radio" name="rdo_brand" value="brand" id="r_brand" onclick="document.getElementById('r_model').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_cc').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=false;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=true;"> Search by brand
<input type="radio" name="rdo_model" value="model" id="r_model" onclick="document.getElementById('r_brand').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_cc').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=false;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=true;"> Search by model
<input type="radio" name="rdo_cc" value="cc" id="r_cc" onclick="document.getElementById('r_brand').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_model').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=false;"> Search by cc

Brand
<select name="brand" id="box_brand" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
<option value="ducati">Ducati</option>
<option value="honda">Honda</option>
</select>

Model
<select name="model" id="box_model" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="k1200gt">K1200GT</option>
<option value="monster">Monster</option>
<option value="silverwing>Silver Wing</option>
</select>

CC
<select name="cc" id="box_cc" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="600">600</option>
<option value="900">900</option>
<option value="1200">1200</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" id="btn_search" />
>/form>
```

And this is my *search.php*:

```
// Data recovery process
// I know it's not the better way but is the most simply for a newbie like me!
if (empty($_POST['brand']))
{
    $brand = 'nothing';
}
else
{
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
}
if (empty($_POST['model']))
{
    $model = 'nothing';
}
else
{
    $model = $_POST['model'];
}
if (empty($_POST['cc']))
{
    $cc = 'nothing';
}
else
{
    $cc = $_POST['cc'];
}

// Replacing spaces in acquired variables
$brand = str_replace(" ", "-", $brand);
$model = str_replace(" ", "-", $model);
$cc = str_replace(" ", "-", $cc);

// Control process
if ($brand <> 'nothing')
{
    header("location: mysite.com/categories/brands/$brand/");
    exit;
}
else
{
    if ($model <> 'nothing')
    {
        header("location: mysite.com/categories/models/$model/");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: mysite.com/categories/cc/$cc/");
        exit;
    }
}
```

I think the code is correct but, obviously, it's not, because doesn't work completely. If I check the *rdo_brand* and I select one of the option inside the *brand* (*bmw* for example), the redirect works fine to *mysite.com/categories/brands/bmw/*... but if I check the *rdo_model* and I select one of the option inside the *model*, the redirect wrongly take me to *mysite.com/categories/cc/nothing/*

I can't understand! Why is this happening?

Comment: Try changing your condition `if ($brand <> 'nothing')` to `if ($brand !=  'nothing')`

Comment: Can you not just use links?

Comment: @TismonVarghese The condition `<>` and `!=` aren't identical? Unfortunately, the result is - wrongly - the same.

@JamesFenwick I don't understand. You suggest to write the links in other way? I must use the complete writing (_mysite.com/categories/brands/SELECTEDBRAND_) because the posts of my blog are hosted in a separated domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing the typos in the html code (see bellow)

```
<form name="admin" method="post" action="/search.php">
<input type="radio" name="rdo_brand" value="brand" id="r_brand" onclick="document.getElementById('r_model').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_cc').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=false;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=true;"> Search by brand
<input type="radio" name="rdo_model" value="model" id="r_model" onclick="document.getElementById('r_brand').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_cc').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=false;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=true;"> Search by model
<input type="radio" name="rdo_cc" value="cc" id="r_cc" onclick="document.getElementById('r_brand').checked=false;document.getElementById('r_model').checked=false;document.getElementById('box_brand').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_model').disabled=true;document.getElementById('box_cc').disabled=false;"> Search by cc

Brand
<select name="brand" id="box_brand" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="bmw">Bmw</option>
<option value="ducati">Ducati</option>
<option value="honda">Honda</option>
</select>

Model
<select name="model" id="box_model" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="k1200gt">K1200GT</option>
<option value="monster">Monster</option>
<option value="silverwing">Silver Wing</option>
</select>

CC
<select name="cc" id="box_cc" />
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="600">600</option>
<option value="900">900</option>
<option value="1200">1200</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" id="btn_search" />
</form>
```

Comment: If the typos is the `>/form`, I assure you that the original HTML is already correct. The typos is carelessly made by copying and adapting the code here.

So, if the rest of the code is errorless, I really cannot explain why dosn't works.

Comment: Damn, I've found another typos in the line `<option value="silverwing>` (as you had already noticed!): fixing it the code works perfectly. What a stupid error; I'm embarassed!

So thanks you all. I hope my code can be useful to web surfers!